# How To make a Layer Only select able In ArcMap through API

Tags: c#, arcgis, arcmap

In ArcMap any Layer can be made only select able through **Right Click->Selection->Make This the Only Select able Layer**.
I want to do it programmatically through ArcMap API. I am a newbie in arcgis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this in this way: very simple solutin, i am a newbie in arcgis

```
private void MakeOnlySelectableLayer(IFeatureLayer stationFeatureLayer)
{
    var Focusmap = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;

    for (int i = 0; i < Focusmap.LayerCount; i++)
    {
        if (Focusmap.get_Layer(i) is IFeatureLayer)
        {
            IFeatureLayer layer = (IFeatureLayer)Focusmap.get_Layer(i);
            if (stationFeatureLayer != null && !stationFeatureLayer.Equals(layer))
            {
              layer.Selectable = false;
            }


        }
     }
 }
```